# How to create separate facets for different measurements with tidyverse?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a novice programmer looking to plot highly grouped variables. Specifically, I am trying to plot a variable that is grouped by 5 other variables. Below is an example data that I am working with.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

set.seed(42)
mydf <- tibble(
  grp = rep(c('A', 'B'), length.out = 32, each = 16),
  sex = rep(c('M', 'F'), length.out = 32, each = 8),
  cond = rep(c('Wet', 'Dry'), length.out = 32, each = 4),
  measure = rep(c('Tempature', 'Volume'), length.out = 32, each = 2),
  kind = rep(c('Experimental', 'Control'), length.out = 32, each = 1),
  value = rnorm(32) * 100,
)


ggplot(mydf, aes(x = grp, y = value, col = cond)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(sex~measure + kind)
```

However, the output is quite messy. Would it be possible to create separate faceted plots for each measurement? What would be a proper way to graph this type of data?

Thank you

Comment: You might try `facet_grid`, which can produce slightly better looking plots with more groups than `facet_wrap`. However unless you have more specific needs out of the charts, it's hard to give a more specific answer. You should possibly ask yourself what grouping variables you are actually interested in and what you want to communicate with your chart, then reduce the grouping variables or make a plot for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of comparison, I would facet on no more than two variables. I would also use `facet_grid()` rather than `facet_wrap()` in such cases, as I think it's just easier to keep track of the different facet dimensions if they are on separate axes.

In your case, you want to distinguish measurements for 5 binary variables.

1. grp
2. sex
3. cond
4. measure
5. kind

With "grp" on the x-axis, "sex" distinguished by colour, and 2 of the remaining 3 on facets, we'll need to introduce another aesthetic parameter to distinguish the last variable.

In *this* case, since there aren't too many points to plot, I suggest **shape**.

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(x = grp, y = value, 
                 color = cond, 
                 shape = kind)) + 
  geom_point(size = 5, stroke = 2) +
  facet_grid(sex~measure) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("Control" = 4, "Experimental" = 16),
                     breaks = c("Experimental", "Control"))
```

[image: plot]

The use of a filled shape vs an un-filled shape makes Experimental points visually distinct from Control points. You can check out other shape options [here](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape).

Note that if there are many different values in your grouping variables (e.g. 5 categories along the x-axis, 6 different colours, 20 facet combinations, etc.), or many points within each facet, the plot will look very busy, and you may want to split into separate plots rather than keep everything together.